# Square 500x500 pixels image has transparent background on all sides of about 125 pixels. Any way to crop that using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a PNG 500x500 pixels image with transparent background, sadly the image has quite a lot of transparent space on top/bottom/left/right side so when I use it in my HTML it looks like it has huge margin or padding because of that transparent space.

The actual part of the image I want to use is the center 250x250 pixels, so that leaves 125px empty transparent space on every side. Is it possible to CSS to somehow make it look as if the sides of the image are cropped?

The images are coming from an API so I can't crop the sides in software like Photoshop.

Here's an example of an image I'm working with - http://raw.communitydragon.org/pbe/game/assets/loadouts/regalia/crests/prestige/prestige_crest_lvl_200.png

Comment: Does the image have empty padding evenly from all the sides, or is it random ?

Comment: The transparent part is evenly spread on all sides. So my goal is to essentially crop 125px on every side.

Comment: Are you okay with using it as a background or you have to use `<img>` ?

Comment: I'm not too sure, I'd have to check if using it as background would work as right now I'm using <img>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to crop it using it as a background.

```css
#image-box{
  background-color: #fafafa;
  background-image: url("http://raw.communitydragon.org/pbe/game/assets/loadouts/regalia/crests/prestige/prestige_crest_lvl_200.png");
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 135%;
  background-position: center center;
} 

img{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="image-box">
  </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

You can check it here: https://codepen.io/bhanusinghR/pen/jONBOJa

Answer (score 1):

You could either use a background as it was already suggested, or give the image a container to clip it:

```css
.clip {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
}
.clip img {
  margin-top: -48px;
  margin-left: -48px;
}
```

```html
<div class="clip">
  <img src="http://raw.communitydragon.org/pbe/game/assets/loadouts/regalia/crests/prestige/prestige_crest_lvl_200.png">
</div>
```